# how to use renderItem of Flatlist in react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to show information of a data i get from an API. the structure of the object is like this :

```
    [
    "Date": 17-12-2020
    "OrderId": 15
    "Order": {
       "Cart": { ... }
       "Information": {
         "ProductInformation": {
            "Customer": {
              "firstname": firstname
              "lastname": lastname
              "adresses": {
                "adresse1":{
                  "city":city
                  "zipCode":zipCode
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
...
    ]
```

I want to extract the `Date`, `firstname`, `lastname` and the `city` from my object and put them in my Component. Can i access them like this :

```
const ProductsList = () => {
  ...
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : ((products !== [])
          && (
          <FlatList
            data={surgeries}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={(element) => {
              return (
                <ProductItem
                  style={{ marginLeft: 35 }}
                  name={element.Order.Information.ProductInformation.Customer.firstname}
                  date={element.Date}
                />
              );
            }}
          />
          )
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Extract `item` in `renderItem` directly or you can access it with `element.item.Date` and so on.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze How to extract item ?

Comment: renderItem(({ item }) => ...